# How to reload exact class after renaming the file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two traits file with the same class:

```
app/Traits/OperationTools_OLD.php
app/Traits/OperationTools.php
```

The two files contain the same class name like the following:

```
<?php
namespace App\Traits;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Http\Helpers\FoxUtils;
use App\Operation;


trait OperationTools {
    use \App\Traits\CavityTools;
   
    public function getProduction(...
```

The app does not recognize the code of the new file `OperationTools.php` and it looks to execute the code of the old one.

I have tried to change the trait name of the old file to be `trait OperationTools_OLD`, but now I get the error when I try to use it:

> Trait 'App\Traits\OperationTools' not found

I think that there is what is like, a class file map, in the app that should be refreshed but I don't know how?

I have tried `artisan config:clear, view:clear` but the issue is the same.

I'm using [laravel-5.4](/questions/tagged/laravel-5.4) and [php-7.4](/questions/tagged/php-7.4) on Ubuntu and Apache.

Comment: I think you must let composer create a new autoload file. Run `composer dump-autoload` for that.

Comment: @GisoStallenberg Yes it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `composer dump-autoload` to create a new autoload file